# Node.js agenda: how to retry jobs after failure?

Tags: node.js

Using [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), is it possible to set jobs to retry after several times after failure?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported at the moment. See https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda/issues/123

Answer (score 2):

If it's a repeating job, you can change the `nextRunAt` value when it fails and it will run again:

```
agenda.on("fail", async (error, job) => {
    const nextRunAt = new Date();
    job.attrs.nextRunAt = nextRunAt;
    await job.save();
});
```

if it's a scheduled job (meaning it doesn't repeat, the above code won't work.  You have to create a new job.

```
agenda.on("fail", async (error, job) => {
    if(job.attrs.repeatInterval) {
        // create a new job and pass it job.attrs.data
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Retry is not directly supported as an option, but it has a simple workaround by setting the failed jobs nextRunAt to a future time.

Refer this article :
https://crossbrowsertesting.com/blog/product-update/task-scheduling-with-agenda/

Comment: The reason why the community guidelines request not to post links, but paste the content instead, is due to links getting killed, like this one. Now people who come looking for the solution are not helped by this reply anymore.